# Not able to style the suggested actions container with limited height and overflow hidden and scrollable

Tags: web-chat

I'm using these style for suggested actions. When the number of suggested actions are more, i want the suggested actions to be in a container with fixed height and overflow hidden with scrollable.
It looks like there are no style options to do the currently. Could you please check if this can done?

```
const styleOptions = {
  suggestedActionBackground: 'White',
  suggestedActionBorder: 0,
  suggestedActionBorderRadius: 4,
  suggestedActionBorderStyle: 'solid',
  suggestedActionBorderWidth: 1,
  suggestedActionHeight: 32,
  suggestedActionLayout: 'stacked', // either "carousel" or "stacked"
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b5zl.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable thru use of CSS, Web Chat's `store`, and an event listener. A couple things to note, however.

One, this requires manipulating the DOM directly. Generally, this is frowned upon in a React environment. Whether you are using the React version of Web Chat or not, Web Chat is built upon React. Because of this, components *may* change in the future which could break this setup. Please bare this in mind.

Two, the example below is a simple setup. You will need to adjust it to meet your needs. For instance, you may need to further isolate certain buttons or specific suggested actions as they arrive.

---

First, we setup our CSS. I have two classes. `hideSuggestedActionsContainer` is used to, initially, hide any suggested actions. If we don't set this immediately, then the CSS changes made to suggested actions will be momentarily visible to the user as they are rendered. `suggestedActionContainer` sets the container styling, including enabling (but hiding) scrolling in the container.

```css
.hideSuggestedActionContainer {
  display: none;
}

.suggestedActionContainer {
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.suggestedActionContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

In Web Chat, we utilize the `store` to manage what actions we take and when. The `store` is passed in as a parameter into Web Chat.

When Web Chat first connects (`DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED`), we assign the `hideSuggestedActionContainer` class to the suggested actions DIV wrapper.

As the suggested action arrives (`WEB_CHAT/SET_SUGGESTED_ACTIONS`), we remove the `hideSuggestedActionContainer` class and assign the `suggestedActionContainer` class allowing the suggested action to be viewed.

At the same time, we monitor the incoming activities (`DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY`) looking for the associated HTML element that houses the suggested action. As Web Chat only allows for one suggested action to be displayed at a time, this *should* be the first object in the `[role=status]` array (again, things could change in the future). From that array, we collect the various suggested action buttons and, when one is clicked, we dispatch an event.

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ({dispatch}) => next => action => {
  if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
    setTimeout( () => {
      let actions = document.querySelectorAll( '[role=status]' );
      let suggestedAction = actions[ 0 ];
      suggestedAction.classList.add( 'hideSuggestedActionContainer' );
    }, 20 )
  }

  if ( action.type === 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SUGGESTED_ACTIONS' ) {
    const { suggestedActions } = action.payload;
    if ( suggestedActions.length > 0 ) {
      setTimeout( () => {
        let actions = document.querySelectorAll( '[role=status]' );
        let suggestedAction = actions[ 0 ];
        suggestedAction.classList.remove('hideSuggestedActionContainer');
        suggestedAction.classList.add( 'suggestedActionContainer' );
      }, 20 )
    }
  }

  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
    const { activity } = action.payload;
    if (activity.type === 'message') {
      const actions = document.querySelectorAll( '[role=status]' );
      const buttons = actions[0].querySelectorAll('button');
      buttons.forEach( button => {
        button.onclick = function() {
          const buttonClick = new Event('buttonClick');
          window.dispatchEvent( buttonClick )
        };
      } )
    }
  }

  next(action);
} );

[ ... ]

window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
  {
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine( {
      token: token
    } ),
    store: store,
    styleOptions: styleOptions
  },
  document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
);
```

Below the Web Chat renderer, we place our event listener. As a suggested action button is clicked, we remove the `suggestedActionContainer` class and re-assign the `hideSuggestedActionContainer` class.

```js
const buttonClickEvent = ( function () {
  window.addEventListener( 'buttonClick', () => {
    let actions = document.querySelectorAll( '[role=status]' );
    let suggestedAction = actions[ 0 ];
    suggestedAction.classList.remove( 'suggestedActionContainer' );
    suggestedAction.classList.add( 'hideSuggestedActionContainer' );
  } );
} )()
```

A note about the `setTimeout()` functions used in the `store`. The `store` processes every activity as it arrives before displaying it. Because of this, a slight delay needs to be applied to the changes we are pushing to the DOM. Without `setTimeout()`, the page tries to render our changes *before* the `store` is able to display the activity's associated HTML. I set the time outs to 20 milliseconds, but you may find you will need to adjust this. I have found that if I set the time out to too low a number then the changes occur before the activity is rendered. If it's too long (300+ ms or thereabouts), then the changes become visible to the user.

[image]

Hope of help!